# Can I do anything if I don't agree with migration to another site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Yesterday I asked this question on SO, [How to completely avoid business logic in DAL?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232422/how-to-completely-avoid-business-logic-in-dal) and soon after it was closed as off-topic and migrated to Programmers (the history is here, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22414212/revisions).

I don't see anything wrong with that question and I sincerely believe this tag and migration was just plain wrong. The explanation - "Without a language tag or some example code, it's not going to get much attention here." is meaningless, since most of design-related questions on SO is without language tag and/or example code. Also number of DDD-related questions on SO is way higher than on Programmers (there are only 191 questions tagged with DDD on Programmers). If I believe that it wasn't fair, can I do something about that?

And in general - if I believe that someone did something wrong, can I challenge it?

P.S. I'm new to meta, I'm not sure if my nagging belongs here, but I'd like to know what's wrong; I did search first and I couldn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: You received two good answers on Programmers, what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: The question was migrated with answers. The problem is what I described in my question - I asked my question on SO, I think this question belongs on SO; this question was tagged as off-topic, and it was moved somewhere else, where it belongs much less - so I'm curious if I can do anything about that. (Also, I'd be more than grateful if you'd explain me why this question was off-topic, so I can refine my further questions.)

Comment: Naturally I'm glad for those answers, but it's like someone pushes you to subway track and you'd find gold nugget between rails - you'd be glad for the nugget, but it doesn't make the initial action good.

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and explain that you disagree with the migration (and why). That said, I see how it might be a better fit for Programmers, and the two additional answers seem to illustrate that. I don't really see a problem here.

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight.  I answered your question on Stack Overflow, but by the time I finished my answer, your question only had 5 views (one of which was mine), and no other answers.  Because the question had no language tag or code in it, I decided to move it to Programmers, where it got 89 views and two new answers, one of which you accepted.  Now you're complaining on meta that the question was migrated.  Really?

Comment: Seriously, are you comparing 5 views in 10 minutes with 89 views in 24 hours? Are you going to move ~ 1000 other DDD questions from ~ 3000 DDD questions on SO without tag or code to programmers, where are ~ 80 DDD questions? I'm not sure if it's technically possible, but (at least for me) it would be much better if you'd just suggested the migration, or explained to me why my question was off-topic on SO.

Comment: OK.  All community members with sufficient reputation have the ability to vote to migrate to another site.  Because I am a moderator, my vote happens to be binding.  I'll ignore your straw man argument about DDD questions for the moment. What problem are we trying to solve here, exactly?

Comment: I wanted to know what can I do if moderator changes my question (when I don't understand why), I believe I got that, thank you. But I'd also appreciate if you can explain to me the rationale behind your action - if I did something wrong, I'd like to understand what's wrong with my post, it's simple as that; so far your explanation was merely "I did that because I can". I posted my DDD question on SO because there are ~ 3000 similar DDD questions, so I'm confused; your rational explanation might be very helpful for my further posts. I asked politely, I believe there's no reason for harsh words.

Comment: Based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange it seems you're right, but now I'm even more confused about the numbers I mentioned.

Comment: It seems as if you feel you're being punished for posting your question to the wrong site.  You aren't, and you didn't.  Generally speaking, looking at *some* of the questions posted on a site to evaluate question topicality is not the best possible approach; site scope can change over time, and there's simply no practical way to go back and fix the scope of every question that was posted in the past.  So your conclusions about the DDD questions have no merit.  The meta post you just linked is a far more productive exercise for evaluating question topicality.

Comment: Over time, Stack Overflow has become increasingly a code troubleshooting site; you can still post conceptual questions there, but it's not the best fit without some code and a language tag.  Programmers still suffers a bit from its reputation in the early days as the "not programming related" site, and Stack Overflow still keeps the most interesting conceptual questions for itself, rather than migrating them to Programmers (which tends to keep Programmers a second-class citizen).  Nevertheless...

Comment: Today there are many thoughtful people over at Programmers who relish discussing conceptual programming topics, and will provide great answers to conceptual programming questions.  The best place to post those questions today is Programmers, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your last three comments describe reality quite accurately, I was wrong and I'm sorry about that. Maybe it wouldn't be a bad idea to move older purely conceptual questions to PSE, so if someone googles question about DDD, CQRS, DI, ..., people will see PSE, instead of SO. Does it make sense?

Comment: We don't migrate old questions; the SE software actually prevents that.  Each new site on the Stack Exchange network is given the benefit of establishing its own community organically, which can't be done if every new site keeps getting old questions from other sites dumped into it.

Comment: I see, it makes sense, you're right. So thanks, and I'm sorry about this migration frenzy.